# Why is the element not centered in the checkbox?

Tags: html, css, web

**Why is the element not centered in the checkbox?**

Must be centered exactly in the middle of the checkbox.

when clicked, it should look like this:

[image]

Tried:

```
left: 50%; top: 50%; - does not seem to work.
```

I do not understand why horizontal scrolling appears when you click on the checkbox.

```
overflow-x: hidden; - not a solution
```

**Code:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  user-select: none;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

input[type='checkbox']+label {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin: .6em 0;
  align-items: center;
  color: #9e9e9e;
}

input[type='checkbox']+label>ins {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 2em;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
}

input[type='checkbox']+label>ins>i {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #000;
}

input[type='checkbox']+label>span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 0.8em;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #E6ECF0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(.4, .0, .23, 1);
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked+label>ins {
  height: 100%;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked+label>span {
  border: .5em solid #7726E5;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked+label>span:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Checkbox</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>

  <section>

    <input id='one' type='checkbox' />
    <label for='one'>
    <span></span>
    Off with your head
    <ins><i>Off with your head</i></ins>
  </label>

    <input id='two' type='checkbox' />
    <label for='two'>
    <span></span>
    Dance ’til you’re dead
    <ins><i>Dance ’til you’re dead</i></ins>
  </label>

    <input id='three' type='checkbox' />
    <label for='three'>
    <span></span>
    Heads will roll
    <ins><i>Heads will roll</i></ins>
  </label>

    <input id='four' type='checkbox' />
    <label for='four'>
    <span></span>
    On the floor
    <ins><i>On the floor</i></ins>
  </label>

  </section>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, it looks pretty well centered to me. The horizontal scroll appears because your black text (which you show on top of the grey text) is inside an element with 100% width, but its parent also contains the checkbox. I'd suggest just making the color of the original label darker, instead of using a second layer of text.

Here's an edit:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; user-select: none; }

section{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

input[type='checkbox']{ height: 0; width: 0; }

input[type='checkbox'] + label{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin: .6em 0;
  align-items: center;
  color: #9e9e9e;
}

input[type='checkbox'] + label > span{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 0.8em;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #E6ECF0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;  
  transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(.4,.0,.23,1);
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked + label > span{
  border: .5em solid #7726E5;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked + label > span:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  border-radius: 2px;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked + label {
  color: unset;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Checkbox</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>

  <section>
  
  <input id='one' type='checkbox' />
  <label for='one'>
    <span></span>
    Off with your head
  </label>
  
  <input id='two' type='checkbox' />
  <label for='two'>
    <span></span>
    Dance ’til you’re dead
  </label>
  
  <input id='three' type='checkbox' />
  <label for='three'>
    <span></span>
    Heads will roll
  </label>
  
  <input id='four' type='checkbox' />
  <label for='four'>
    <span></span>
    On the floor
  </label>
  
</section>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

  

</body>

</html>
```

If you want the white square in the middle of your checkbox to be wider (as it looks in your png), you should make the border smaller here:

```
input[type='checkbox']:checked + label > span{
  border: .5em solid #7726E5;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, how can I make a white square with rounded corners in the middle of my checkbox?

Comment: The inner radius of the border (which does the inside rounding) is calculated as the difference between the `border-radius` and `border-width`. To achieve an inner rounding, you need your `border-radius` to be bigger than your `border-width`.
[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uavr6x5f/3/) can work for your case and [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/0ovkrm3e/) is 10 times bigger, so you can actually see what's happening easily.